# How do we get $ \frac{d u(t+s,x+sb)}{d s} = \frac{\partial u(t+s,x+sb)}{\partial t} + b \cdot \Delta u(t+s, x+sb)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm doing a course in PDEs, and the equation in the title came up in the process of finding a general analytic solution to the transport equation. We assume a solution u(t,x), then introduce $z(s)=u(t+s,x+sb)$ for a fixed t and x. We take the derivative with respect to s, $z'(s) = \frac{d}{ds} u(t+s,x+sb)$. Apparently, this then gives $$z'(s) = \frac{d}{ds} u(t+s,x+sb)=u_t(t+s,x+sb)+b \cdot \nabla u(t+s,x+sb)$$

To make things easier, let's assume $x \in \mathbb{R}^1$. My understanding would be that this should behave as though we had $u(f(t,s),g(x,s))$ where $f(t,s)= t+s$ and $g(x,s)=x+sb$. That would then mean that when we take the total derivative with respect to s, we would get
$$\frac{d}{ds} u(f(t,s),g(x,s)) = \frac{\partial u (f,g)}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial u(f,g)}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g(s,t)}{\partial s}$$
It's pretty clear that $\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial s}=1$ and $\frac{\partial g(s,t)}{\partial s} =b$, which would result in
$$\frac{d u}{d s} = \frac{\partial u (f,g)}{\partial f}  + b\frac{\partial u(f,g)}{\partial g} $$
But that should then be
$$\frac{d u}{d s} = \frac{\partial u (t+s,x+sb)}{\partial (t+s)}  + b\frac{\partial u(t+s,x+sb)}{\partial (x+sb)} $$
I'm not sure I understand *why* we can then completely ignore the $s$ in the variable we're taking the derivative with respect to. I tried this out with a simple equation and saw that it can work, but I'm absolutely stuck as to why this is true.

Comment: First, there are some problems with your question. I think you meant to write 'We assume a solution $u(t, \color{red}{x})$' and it should be $b \cdot \color{red}{\nabla}$. Then to answer your question, it is just a notational issue. After computing the total differential, the author has just _relabeled_ $f(t,s) \to t, g(x,s) \to x$. Remember, $f, g$ are just dummy variables, so you can label it however you want.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're totally right regarding the mistakes there. I'll edit the post. If it is just a notational change, then I'll feel a lot better about that.

Comment: It is notation. If I remember correctly, this is how Evans does it in his 'Partial Differential Equations' book, which is one of the core graduate level textbooks on PDEs.

Comment: Yep, that's the book my prof is working from. Here I was thinking I had forgotten some fundamental thing of derivatives!